# How to access dynamic values in script assertion; which are set at test case level?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have set a dynamic value at test case level for the below response.

```
{
   "orderDetails": {"serviceOrderNumber": "SO-EUAM-MX-EUAM-16423"},
   "transactionDetails":    {
      "statusMessage": "Success",
      "startRow": "1",
      "endRow": "400",
      "totalRow": "1",
      "timeZone": "EST"
   },
   "customerNodeDetails":    {
      "startDate": "20180622 06:32:39",
      "nodeCreateDate": "20180622 06:32:39",
      "customerId": "5562"
   }
}
```

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('CustID', json.customerNodeDetails.customerId.toString())
```

Now while asserting another API which is a GET one, I am getting the `CustID` as `customerNumber`.

I have used the below code:

```
assert json.customerNodeDetails.customerNumber == "${#TestCase#CustID}"
```

and the block of response for the same was:

```
"customerNodeDetails":    {
      "nodeLabel": null,
      "customerNumber": "5544",
      "customerName": "ABCDEFGHIJ ABCDEFGHIJ LMNOPQRSTUV1234",
      "taxIdCity": "",
      "taxIdState": "",
      "salesSegment": "Government",
      "dunsNumber": "",
      "mdsId": "",
      "accountClassification": "B",
      "specialCustomerBillCode": ""
}.
```

But I am getting the below error as:

> startup failed: Script65.groovy: 26: unexpected char: '#' @ line 26, column 54. eDetails.customerNumber == "${#TestCase# ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected char: '#' @ line 26, column 54. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:138) at

Please let me know how to access that value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a property within a Groovy script, you can't use it directly as you might in other parts of the UI. You need to expand it:

```
def custID = context.expand('${#TestCase#CustID}')
```

Or, the `messageExchange` variable available in script assertions gives you an alternative way to do the same thing:

```
def alternative = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue('CustID');
```

Then, if you need a property that's defined somewhere else other than at the test-case level, you can use:

```
def projectLevelProperty = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase
              .testSuite.project.getPropertyValue('projectLevelProperty');
```